# Record insert/delete anomaly

Tags: excel, ms-access, error-handling

I have the next problem to which I need help to solve.
There is a Workbook with three forms and a Database in Access.

There is a table in the DB called tblPlanungStatus where I record if a module is ready.
All three forms uses the table to either delete or insert a status into it.

There is an anomaly that occurs most of the time from Form3.
I insert the status, it runs without error. I run a query to count the recorords for this type and it comes back 1. Wich is good.
In the DB nothing happens, it shows no record added.
I run the query again and it says there is 1 record.
I run delete and the count says 0. So it seems to work. But in the DB still nothing.

I close the Workbook and run the count again and the record dissapeared, in the DB nothing shows.
If the record stays in the DB then when deleting it works, but after closing it comes back again.

Sometimes the record cannot be added, sometimes it cannot be deleted and when reopening the Workbook (which I don't know why matters) the record either deletes or adds.
In the DB the record appears and dissapears with a certain time, but not always.

I have been stuggling with this for over a week. Can anyone help me?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

Probably your Access database corrupted. Check [this](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html), especially "Number of records varies, depending how the data is sorted"

Comment: This started suddenly one day. The indexes remained the same and the same structure worked a week ago. It only happens when I close the Workbook and reopen it. :S

Comment: And the same thing, the same code, the same table, the same record works from a different form.
There's no real difference between the two forms in these procedures.